# Upload file to a 777 folder using PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, amazon-ec2, 777

I am working on a school project which involves a Supermarket system and I have a Shop PC (localhost) and a HQ server (hosted on Amazon EC2). One of the requirements is that Shop PC will generate a transaction file (I have a button which generates the file) and that text file needs to be sent over to the HQ server. I have created a folder with 777 permissions on the HQ server. I was trying to simply send over/upload the file to that folder using the ***copy*** function of PHP but that does not work. Any clues on how I can do that? I do not have ftp installed on amazon and cannot do that as per the requirements.

Also, i cannot create an upload form (multipart form?) on the HQ admim to upload the file because the shop guy can't access the HQ server pages.

The address of the folder where the files need to be uploaded is:

```
"site address"/uploads
```

I create the transaction file in the following manner:

```
$ourFileName = "transaction.txt";
    $ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    //fwrite($fh, $stringData);

    $sql = mysql_query("the query");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $stringData = "data";
        fwrite($ourFileHandle, $stringData);
    }

    fclose($ourFileHandle);
```

This file is created on the shop PC and i want to send it to the HQ server, where it can be parsed and added to the HQ database. To the send the file to the uploads folder in the HQ sever, i follow the above code with:

```
$filename = "news.txt";
    $newfile = "siteaddress/uploads/" . $filename;
    if(copy($ourFileName, $newfile)) 
    {
    print("<h3> UPLOAD SUCCESSFUL!</h3>");
    } 
    else
    {
    print("<h3>ERROR UPLOADING FILE!</h3>");
    }
```

**Edit after following the discussions:**

The HQ server has php. Infact it has a file parser defined in parse_transaction.php which begins like:

```
<?php
include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql_HQ.php"; 
mysql_query($sql);
mysql_query($sql2);
mysql_query($sql3);

$filename= mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

$lines = file($filename); // slurp file and split into an array by lines
```

perhaps somehow possible to send the transaction file directly here for parsing and updating without storing it in the uploads folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the file get transferred with the wrong write/read/execute attributes or not at all?

If the file does not get transferred have you checked for php log errors?

If you are using copy, then i assume you have the partition mounted so you have direct access to the files on the HQ server, if not you could try setting up your php for receiving files, take a look at this:

```
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php
```

And if you don't have php on the server, how do you access its files?

Comment: the file doesn't get transferred at all.
Seeing the previous comments I guess i cannot use copy as i am trying to copy the file from local server to remote server. Plus if I create a form, then the upload will need to be done manually?

Comment: the transaction file will be parsed using a parser written in php and then the details will be used to update the database for that shop

Comment: You can upload a file from a php server to another php server, using the post upload method earlier mentioned, if you want to do that, you might want to look over cURL, and enabling that in your php.ini on your 'clientside' server, look at http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html for '4.3 File Upload POST'

Comment: This sounds perfect! I also had a form in the HQ server to upload the transaction files. Can I post to that form directly? That would solve the problem! Can you expand a bit more on how to use the CURL statement

Comment: Yes, you can post them directly, and here are two good references to get started:
http://se2.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php http://se2.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 0):

Generate the file in Shop PC and store it somewhere can be accessed (read) by HQ Server.

PHP command `copy` should be used in HQ Server to get the file from Shop PC.

```
copy('http://somedomain.com/transaction.txt', '/tmp/transaction.txt');
```

Note that you need `allow_url_fopen` has to be `= on` in `php.ini`.

Comment: this would involve the HQ admin to manually check each and every Shop PC, if it has a transaction file or not. Not a scaleable solution

Comment: Your shop PC may send a HTTP request to HQ Server after the file is generated, so we can make sure there is a transaction file.